# PhoneGap loading external page instead of index.html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cordova

I am trying to load an external site instead of the internal index.html file found in the www folder in PhoneGap.. But have not been sucessful. I've tried several things that I found online but they all address just loading external links within the wrapper instead of safari.

Which is not what I am looking for... I am looking for when the phonegap application loads that it loads a page hosted on my web server instead of the index.html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, you need to modify the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method in your AppDelegate.m file :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if ( [ [url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [ [url scheme] 
                                                     isEqualToString:@"https"] )   
    { 
        return YES; 

    } else { 

        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request 
                navigationType:navigationType]; 
    } 
}
```

Then, you can have change you local index.html in the www folder with :

```
<html> 
<body onload="document.location.href='http://yourComputerIpOrServer/index.html';"> 
<h1>Loading....</h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Of course, this is for debugging only. You should not submit it to the AppStore, it's prohibited and it will be rejected.

Comment: You can do this in PhoneGap.plist now by switching OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES and adding your domain as an external host.

Answer (score 2):

You can load external URLs in the webview. Make sure to set

```
super.setBooleanProperty("loadInWebView", true);
```

in your onCreate() method of your main class (which extends DroidGap) and then you can load external URLs.

Comment: I am not looking for a droid solution that I have... but an iphone version of doing the same thing...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain this is by design. Most of the application stores require approval of applications. If you dynamically load your application they can't control it.

[Example discussion of this on the mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/phonegap/2011-05/msg01299.html)

Comment: There has got to be a way.. I've seen plenty of applications that do such a thing.

Comment: I hope there is -- I'm interested in the answer too.